# Create different files based off value in dataframe column A and save to different existing folders based off value in dataframe column A

Tags: python, pandas

1. First, I would like to create different files based off the value in dataframe column A `FTP_FOLDER_PATH`
2. Second, I would like to save these files to different folders depending on the value in dataframe column A 'FTP_FOLDER_PATH'. These folders already exist and do not need to be created.

I am struggling with how to do this through looping. I have done something similar in the past for the first part, where I just create different files, but I could only figure out how to save them to one folder. I am stuck on trying to save them to multiple folders. In the code, I have included:

1. the dataframe
2. what I have attempted which only solves the first part of the problem and
3. the desired output which all needs to go to the correct FTP folders.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import os

FTP_Master_Folder = 'C:/FTP'

df = pd.DataFrame({'FTP_FOLDER_PATH' : ['C:\FTP1', 'C:\FTP2', 'C:\FTP2', 'C:\FTP2', 'C:\FTP3', 'C:\FTP3'],
               'NAME' : ['Jon', 'Kat', 'Kat', 'Kat', 'Joe', 'Joe'],
               'CARS' : ['Honda', 'Lexus', 'Porsche', 'Saleen s7', 'Tesla', 'Tesla']})
df

for i, x in df.groupby('FTP_FOLDER_PATH'):
#How do I change the below line to loop through and change the directory based on the value of the 'FTP_FOLDER_PATH'
    os.chdir(f'{FTP_Master_Folder}')
    p = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),  i + '.csv')
    x.to_csv(p, index=False)

#Desired Ouput to specific FTP folder based on row of dataframe
df_FTP1 = pd.DataFrame({'FTP_FOLDER_PATH' : ['C:\FTP1'],
               'NAME' : ['Jon'],
               'CARS' : ['Honda']})
df_FTP1
df_FTP2 = pd.DataFrame({'FTP_FOLDER_PATH' : ['C:\FTP2', 'C:\FTP2', 'C:\FTP2'],
               'NAME' : ['Kat', 'Kat', 'Kat'],
               'CARS' : ['Lexus', 'Porsche', 'Saleen s7']})
df_FTP2
df_FTP3 = pd.DataFrame({'FTP_FOLDER_PATH' : ['C:\FTP3', 'C:\FTP3'],
               'NAME' : ['Joe', 'Joe'],
               'CARS' : ['Tesla', 'Tesla']})
df_FTP3
```

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a minor basic error. I should have included **/{i}** in line 2. i would be the subfolder of the masterfolder in this case, so adding this in allows the files to go to their destinations, so that solves part two of my problem quite easily.

```
for i, x in df_joined.groupby('FTP_FOLDER_PATH'):        
    os.chdir(f'{FTP_Master_Folder}/{i}')
    p = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),  i + '.csv')
    x.to_csv(p, index=False)
```